# spring WebClient Http to http Proxy multipartFormData No suitable writer found for part

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

background: i use webClient proxy httpRequest to another httpServer,but the contentType is mulitpart request can not correct requet, i need u help

**1.this is proxy webClient**

```java
public static Mono<ServerResponse> forwardRequest(String uri, ServerRequest request, int timeoutInMillis) {
        RequestBodySpec requestBodySpec = WEB_CLIENT_IGNORE_SSL.method(
                        Objects.requireNonNull(request.method()))
                .uri(uri)
                .headers(httpHeaders -> request.headers().asHttpHeaders().forEach((k, h) -> {
                    if (!HOP_BY_HOP_HEADERS.contains(k.toUpperCase()) && !HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH.equalsIgnoreCase(k)) {
                        httpHeaders.addAll(k, h);
                    }
                }))
                .httpRequest(httpRequest -> {
                    HttpClientRequest nativeRequest = httpRequest.getNativeRequest();
                    nativeRequest.responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(timeoutInMillis));
                });

        RequestHeadersSpec<?> afterSetBody;
        Optional<MediaType> mediaType = request.headers().contentType();
        if (mediaType.isPresent() && mediaType.get().isCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)) {
            afterSetBody = requestBodySpec.body(request.formData(), new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
            });
        } else if (mediaType.isPresent() && mediaType.get().isCompatibleWith(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)) {
            //multipartData has been read before
            afterSetBody = requestBodySpec.body(request.multipartData().log(), new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
            });
        } else {
            afterSetBody = requestBodySpec.body(request.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class), DataBuffer.class);
        }
        Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>> responseEntityMono = afterSetBody
                .retrieve()
                //透传下游请求返回的httpCode
                .onStatus(httpStatus -> true, clientResponse -> Mono.empty())
                .toEntityFlux(DataBuffer.class);

        return responseEntityMono.flatMap(responseEntity -> {
            Flux<DataBuffer> body = responseEntity.getBody();
            return ServerResponse.status(responseEntity.getStatusCode())
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                        responseEntity.getHeaders().forEach((k, v) -> {
                            if (!HOP_BY_HOP_HEADERS.contains(k.toUpperCase())) {
                                httpHeaders.addAll(k, v);
                            }
                        });
                    })
                    .body(body == null ? Flux.empty() : body, DataBuffer.class);
        });
    }
```

** 2.client use postman request**

[image]

```
curl --location 'localhost:8081/post/forward/test/form-url-encode?test=999' \
--header 'Swimlane: xxx' \
--form 'test="xxx"' \
--form 'app_id="666"'
```

**3.server recevied request**
when server receive the request, the error occured :

```
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: No suitable writer found for part: test
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageWriter.encodePart(MultipartHttpMessageWriter.java:260) ~[spring-web-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageWriter.lambda$encodePartValues$4(MultipartHttpMessageWriter.java:213) ~[spring-web-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:376) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:219) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8642) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:451) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at
```